# Why it takes too long to make simple cuts in blender VSE?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

Basically I have a gameplay video that I made it is 37 minutes.
I want to store minutes 0-26 and throw out the rest.
I did that using blender.
Then I saved the edit by pressing animate. It took 2 hours.

Of course I have tried to activate GPU rendering. It still takes a long time.

To add insult, this is not really "rendering". I only make simple cuts for the video. So basically render will simply copy and paste the first 20 minutes of the video and remove 17 minutes of the rest.

For comparison, AZScreen, an app in android, can do the same thing within seconds.

I made a video to show you what the problem is.
https://youtu.be/bcX4MPp0txI

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

The result is of poor quality. Far worse than the original that is produced while playing video games within 37 minutes.

I tried cycle render to see if it's faster because of using GPU.

The old video is overwritten. I am mad. I do not tell blender to overwrite existing video. I thought it'll make another video.

Comment: Its a common problem of movie editing tools. It will even occur in high end software like premiere or after effects. Because the video can't just simply cut the rest out. Instead it has to create a whole new video and has to render the 26 minutes again. Maybe there is a special cutting software. But with blender this is not possible. What you could do, is switching the Frame Rate from 60 to 30. This will cut your render time into half. Also maybe you want to post a screenshot of your output setting (what movie format are you using?). 4 Hours sounds high. Maybe the setup is not optimal

Comment: I totally agree with Demons. One addition: You should always think good about whether you really need to edit your video with blender. If you want to add special effects, a robot army or whatever, the answer is YES ofc. But whenever one needs to make just a few cuts (as you do) one should get some basic (and free) video editor software from the internet. Exactly for the reason you just discovered and Demons explained. The advantage of easy video editors: they can copy video files and render just the transitions - so they are way faster and more suitable for *easy* tasks.

Comment: Okay that's one solution. Use other software. Any idea? Also why does using GPU doesn't help a bit? The time is the same.

Comment: You can see in the video that GPU doesn't help at all.

Comment: As i know, Blender compositor does not use GPU acceleration. The cuda settings are only for cycles rendering.

Comment: So I should change blender render to blender game or cycles render?

Comment: Other softwares: http://www.smallbusinesscomputing.com/slideshows/open-source-video-editors-for-small-business.html
http://www.videolan.org/vlmc/
http://www.openshot.org/
to name just a few. But I never tried those, though. And ofc there are a lot more out there, so maybe it's good to search one more time also

Comment: isn't that strange that blender default to blender render

Comment: @JimThio No, changing the render engine will change nothing. The point is, that the blender video composer is a complete independent render engine. if you change the 3d render engine (cycles, internal, game) it has nothing to do with the video composer. if you are rendering a video file, you simply NEVER (under no circumstances) can user your GPU. GPU only works if you are rendering in 3D Space.

Comment: The blender VSE although powerful, crude and a integrated part of blender. It is pretty jacked up. Much easier to cut in Adobe Premiere. It should be rewritten to function more like premier from keys to behavior. It is useless on big projects and takes a lot of finagling even on the smallest of projects. I wish they would fix it so I could ditch Premiere. I cut for a living.

Answer (score 5):

When "rendering" a video from the VSE, blender essentially plays all of the source videos frame by frame that will be used to make up the current frame, it then merges each video frame with any effect strips to get the final image for the frame and sends that final frame to ffmpeg to be compressed using the encoding options. These steps will always be performed even if only one unaltered video stream is in the VSE and you want it saved using the same compression settings as the original video.

If you only want to cut a part of a video and keep the same video compression settings, you will find other software better suited. The ffmpeg cli command is one fast option, when you specify that the video and audio is to be copied, it will not decode/encode the video which makes it almost as fast as just copying the file. `-c:v copy` will copy the video track and `-c:a copy` does the same for audio with `-ss 00:10:00` specifying the start time and `-t 00:36:25` being the duration.

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -ss 00:10:00 -t 00:36:25 cut.mp4
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you do nothing wrong. Video Editing just isn't as easy, as you imagine it.

Cutting a video stream is more complex than just cutting a piece of paper. Most video formats are compressed and among other techniques this compression uses special image sequences.

Video compression in short is done by saving pixels, thus reducing the amount of data. The best method to save pixels is to reduce them to the ones that actually change between similar images.

The common method is to have keyframe images (I-Frames) which contain all the information a still image would have. Between them you have a "prediction" of the changes that might happen in the next frame. Those frames are called P-Frames (P for prediction. See, there's a pattern here) and would contain only those pixels which change between the I-Frames.  These are followed by images that contain both the resulting P-Frame and a prediction to the following I-Frame, thus they are bidirectional and called B-Frames.

A simple mpeg(2) sequence for example would be "I-Frame -> P-Frame -> B-Frame ->I-Frame".

The thing is, that depending on where you cut the video, the software decides if it should recalculate it or not. If in the above example you would cut your video right before an I-Frame and the following cut would also be  before an I-Frame, your video gets recalculated to match the sequence described above.

Another reason why a software wants to "verify" or recalculate the whole video is obviously a change in the format. This not only concerns the video format but also the audio as well. Keep in mind to check what formats (audio and video) your recording has and choose the exact same settings to export.

If this explanation answers your question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: avidemux can do it fast but blender can't that's the issue with the question. your answer doesn't explain why blender is so slow (compared to avidemux)

Comment: @JimThio - Yes, it does. Blender tries to do the best possible job by verifying the source material, while avidemux is programmed to work "quick and dirty". I won't go into detail any further and I hinted already that digital video editing is not that easy.